# Why is navigator.js separate from base.js

Tags: windows-8, winjs

The code for the `PageControlNavigator` class is stored in `navigator.js` (which gets added automatically by the Navigation App template in VS), but the code for the `PageControl` class is stored in `base.js`. What's the reason for having a completely separate JS file just for the `PageControlNavigator` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt anyone but Microsoft can tell you definitively, but the separation is likely because navigator.js is designed to be modified by the developer to suit their needs (for example, custom handling of navigation events or changing how the keyboard controls navigation,) whereas base.js cannot/should not be modified.

navigator.js is really just a convenient way to deal with the Page Controls. It does not actually do anything to implement them. You could roll your own navigator.js if you wanted to, and the page controls would work the exact same way.

Comment: I was on the team who built these pieces, and can confirm that Paul's statements are basically correct - we needed to provide a basic "navigation framework", but didn't want to lock everyone into one specific one. So we provided the basic one in navigator.js in a way that you can easily modify or even throw it out as your needs change.